# How to copy calculated value into selected cell on a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

My current calculation, returns the value into a msgbox.

I would like a further msgbox asking "do you want to paste the value", then be able to select a cell to paste the value into.

I can't work out how to retain the calculation result to be able to paste it.

```vb
Sub CalcmsgboxAcre()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim num As Double
    num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Enter The Number Of Hectares You Would Like To Calculate Into Acres ", Type:=1)
    MsgBox Format(num * 2.471054, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Acre's."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to save the result, after showing the result you just need to ask if the user wants it saved by doing

```
Save = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)
```

Then, if the answer is yes you need to ask the cell and paste the result there

```
If Save = vbYes Then
    cell = Application.InputBox("In which cell")
    Range(cell).Value = num * 2.471054
End If
```

Hope this helps,
Bruno

Comment: Hi Bruno, i have tried to do it like this and the debugger halts on the save command:  Sub CalcmsgboxAcre()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim num As Double
    num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Enter The Number Of Hectares You Would Like To Calculate Into Acres ", Type:=1)
    MsgBox Format(num * 2.471054, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Acre's."
    Save = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)
    If Save = vbYes Then
        cell = Application.InputBox("In which cell")
        Range(cell).Value = num * 2.471054
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I have tested it, and it's worked fine, can you tell exactly what error it's returning? and is it on Save = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)?

Comment: Yes it halts on the Save = MsgBox,,, compile error, expected function or variable.

Comment: it works, but enters the incorrect value when you specify the cell reference.

Comment: Are you saying it's incorrect because it's not rounded to the second decimal place? if so try changing Range(cell).Value = num * 2.471054 to Range(cell).Value = Round(num * 2.471054, 2)